# sql 1 to 1 relationship table setup

Tags: sql

If I have a parent item Report, called Report and each report has 1 supReportA, subReportB and subReportC.  And each subReport belongs to only 1 report, a 1 to 1 relationship,
should I set up the tables with the Report table having

```
    Report
    -------
    Id
    subReportAId
    subReportBId
    subReportCId
```

Or should I set up the tables where each subReport has the Report Id

```
    SubReportA
    -----------
    Id
    ReportId

    SubReportB
    ----------
    Id
    ReportId

    SubReportC
    ----------
    Id
    ReportCId
```

Which way is best practice and why?  thanks for the help in advance....

Answer (score 1):

Since you have this role that one report has only one type of each sub report and vice-versa the correct model to you would be:

Table report

```
Report
id PK
```

Table Subreport

```
Subreport
id PK
idReport (FK->report)
idTypeSubReport (FK->typeSubReport)
(add a unique with id,idReport)
```

And table TypeSubReport

```
TypeSubReport
id
description
```

This way you will not have duplicated data anywhere.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the proper model if you need a subReport type dimension.

Answer (score 0):

you can have JUNCTION table which maps parent report to subreport 
The main Report table can have a entry for both parent report and subreports.

### Report

```
 Id
 subReportAId
 subReportBId
 subReportCId
```

### ReportAssociation

```
parentReportId  subReportId
Id               subReportIDA
Id               subReportIDB
Id               subReportIDC
```

Comment: wouldn't a junction table be for a many to many?  That seems unnecessary.  I can get the job done with either of the two scenarios I provided, I really don't want to add another table if I don't need to.

Comment: @user1220099, how do you indicate that subreports a,b,c are for report 1 and subreports d,e,f are for report2

Comment: by using the Ids.  So either report 1 has an id for each subreport or each subreport has an id for the report.  I'm just trying to figure out best practice.

Comment: @user1220099, the junction table will tell you the relation ship. the main table can have configuration of each report with out need to tell whether sub report or main report.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a junction table bringing all the subreports and main report into the same table of data.

Comment: isn't that for a many to many setup?  Each report only has 1 of each subreport and each subreport has 1 report, so they are all 1 to 1....

Answer (score 0):

There are a few factors to consider.

1. Will each subReport type have different detail columns associated with them, or do they share these in common?
2. Will you be adding new subReport types in the future? If they are all in the same table it is as easy as adding a row, if not then you need to add new table/view.
3. How are you going to be using this data? Is it for reporting, transaction processing, how do you need to access and update it?

My personal opinion would be to keep it simple, that is treat them as a subReport type in a child table to the Report table. This would mean a one Report to many subReport relationship.

Comment: so would you put the Ids for the subreport in the Report table or the Id for the Report in each of the subreport tables?  That's what I'm trying to figure out...

Comment: Since a report can have many subReports you cannot put it in the Report table as it would lead you to duplicate report ids. You would put the report id in the subReport table since each subReport ID can only have one parent report id.